# Sending parameters of Objective-C to C ++

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

I am a beginner in programming for Objective-c, and a few days ago I learned that the same compiler running Objective-c can also run files from the C / C ++.

I realized some searches on the internet and could not find an example and practice to my understanding, so I'm trying to create a simple code in Objective-c where we have a number to be sent to an existing .cpp file in my project, and the .cpp take that number and multiply it by 2, and then the .cpp file returns me the number multiplied to the Objective-c, and then I show the console.

Below is a small example of a part of code done in Objective-c:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    int myNumber = 45;

    /*

    HERE COMES THE CODE WHO WILL SELECT THE FILE 'MULTI.CPP' AND SEND THE VAR 'MYNUMBER' TO 
    THIS PROJECT.


    */

    int returnNumber = /*  HERE COMES A CODE THAT WILL GET THE NUMBER MULTIPLIED BY 2 */


}
```

So..I have no idea to do this kind of thing, but for me I think it's a very simple thing to do. I do not know if this is the correct way to send parameters of Objective-C to C, I thought this way because I'm used to send parameters of Objective-C for PHP, and in it you can send an easy way.

As you guys saw my code is incomplete, in my case what are the commands that could be placed there so the number **'45'** can be sent to for a .cpp project, and then after processing be sent back to the objetive- c?

Answer (score 0):

.c = C language. .cpp = C++ language. .m = Objective-C language. .mm = Objective-C++ language.

C code can only call C code. C++ code can call C code (with precautions) or C++ code. Objective-C code can call C and Objective-C code, and can contain C code. Objective-C++ code can call C, C++, Objective-C and Objective-C++ code, and contain C, C++ and Objective-C code.